# Can't view first item on PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create PageView related to my object but when i load,the first item does not show. It is blank like in the screenshot. Print function works fine ,it prints the existing item but i can't view it .

**Print Result** `item : itemfirst`

```
 Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: colordtmainone,
        body: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: colordtmainone,
                toolbarHeight: 0,
                expandedHeight: 0,
                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              ),
            ];
          },
          body:  PageView.builder(
            onPageChanged: (indexpage){
              if (indexpage + 1 == _userservicesForDisplay.length) {
                page = page +1;
                _loadmoreuserservices();
              }
            },
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         for(final item in _userservicesForDisplay)print('item: ${item.service}');
              return index == 0 ? SizedBox(height:0,width:0) : _listItemUserService(index-1);},
            itemCount: _userservicesForDisplay.length+1,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your are skipping the first element. If `index = 0`, it returns a SizedBox(height:0,width:0).

```
return index == 0 ? SizedBox(height:0,width:0) : _listItemUserService(index-1);},
```

So you can

```
itemBuilder: (_, index) {
   return _listItemUserService(index);
},
itemCount: _userservicesForDisplay.length,
```

Comment: I am choosing this as an answer because it should be true.But somehow items keep duplicating due to an internal issue inside Flutter. I consider the issue solved!